# hardware event on Power8

Tags: performancecounter, powerpc

I am experimenting PAPI and hardware counter on Power8. I think very is an issue with PM_FLOP computation (used by PAPI_flop). PM_FLOP is the sum of the following counter: PM_VSU{i}_{j}FLOP where i is (1,2)  (2 VSU per core)", j is (1,2,4,8). This 2 numbers matches nevertheless if we analyses the matrix-hl.c test of PAPI test (matrix multiplication), we can have a pb.

At the end of the test there is error catcher:

```
 if ( event[0] == PAPI_FP_INS ) {
            /*     Compare measured FLOPS to expected value */
            tmp =
                    2 * ( long long ) ( NROWS1 ) * ( long long ) ( NCOLS2 ) *
                    ( long long ) ( NCOLS1 );
    printf("%llu \n",tmp);
            if ( abs( ( int ) values[0] - ( int ) tmp ) > ( float ) tmp * 0.05 ) {
                    /*     Maybe we are counting FMAs? */
                    tmp = tmp / 2;
                    if ( abs( ( int ) values[0] - ( int ) tmp ) >
                             ( float ) tmp * 0.05 ) {
                            printf( "\n" TAB1, "Expected operation count: ", 2 * tmp );
                            printf( TAB1, "Or possibly (using FMA):  ", tmp );
                            printf( TAB1, "Instead I got:            ", values[0] );
                            test_fail( __FILE__, __LINE__,
                                               "Unexpected FLOP count (check vector operations)",
                                               1 );
                    }
            }
  }
```

There is no error nevertheless If I remove the first branching and compile the test with -O3  for float and double I get

```
Expected operation count:      11812500
Or possibly (using FMA):        5906250
Instead I got:                  3003761
matrix-hl.c - DOUBLE                             FAILED

Expected operation count:      11812500
Or possibly (using FMA):        5906250
Instead I got:                  1552507
matrix-hl.c - FLOAT                              FAILED
```

Presently I think the computation of PM_FLOP is wrong. For me every PM_VSU{i}_{j}FLOP  is not the number of flop but the number of mnemonic that is completed. Consequently PM_VSU{i}_{j}FLOP should be correct by factor: x1 for M_VSU{i}_1FLOP, x2 for M_VSU{i}_2FLOP, x4 for M_VSU{i}_4FLOP and x8 for M_VSU{i}_8FLOP.

In fact the original test works because by default we are compiling with -O0 consequently the ASM generated has only serial operations, measured by M_VSU{i}_1FLOP, where 1 scalar mnemonic is one flop. I did some test on dgemm and basic vector addition and FMA, that's confirme my correction.

Any propositions from an IBM-Power guru ?

Best,

++t

Comment: From what I barely remember you are right, in the sense that the hardware counter should count the number of floating point instructions (FLIPs vs FLOPs), being them ADDs, MULs or FMAs, and in this case I wouldn't consider it a bug, just that it's not useful to directly evaluate actual GFlops. But I was working on Power3/4/5 when I met them. It's possible that IBM has introduced FP operations counters in newer processors and so this is a bug actually.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, I really need this flops for some performance model. I will try to forward  the info to IBM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I think you're right.

Looking at the documentation (from `ophelp`):

```
PM_VSU1_8FLOP: (counter: 0, 1, 2, 3)
    eight flops operation (DP vector versions of fdiv,fsqrt and SP vector versions of 
    fmadd,fnmadd,fmsub,fnmsub) (min count: 10000)
```

Which is not very clear, but implies that a count of 1 for this event means 8 FLOPs were executed.